# How to chose which line goes on top of the other line

Tags: carto, cartocss

I am trying to do something very simple, but apparently impossible. Overlay two lines with different size and color signing same route different direction.
Like this one:
http://www.indianatrails.org/Pleasant_Ride/index.html

I couldn't find in CARTODB a way to put on top the green route.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the order in CartoDB in two different ways: having the geometries in different layers and moving a layer on top of the other one, or ordering the results of your table.

CartoDB draws the geometries by using the cartodb_id index by default. This means that a line with cartodb_id = 10 will be always plotted on top of other one with cartodb_id=9. If you're building the visualization on runtime and getting the data from a query, the system will take into account if you have a ORDER BY statement applied. If so, geometries will be drawn in an ascendent way with respect to the statement key.

So, basically, you need to set up a query that returns your data in the order you need. You can use a column to give priority to your blue lines over some green ones, and use a ORDER BY over it.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that you create different layers in your CartoCSS editor. CartoCSS create different layers when rendering based on the order you define them.

For example you could do:

```
#table_name[line_type = 'red']::z1{
  line-color: #FF6600;
  line-width: 2;
  line-opacity: 0.7;
}

#table_name[line_type = 'green']::z2{
  line-color: #229A00;
  line-width: 1;
  line-opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Where 'green' or 'red' are cell values of a column called 'line_type'

Comment: I have used ORDER BY and it works well. It keeps the same order for all the visualizations. If I understood correctly using CartoCSS it allows to make changes specifically to the table or visualization you are working on it leaving intact the other ones.